# How to get total row in the selected table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem to use query to get the total row value in the table. I have used below method to get the total row value in the table, but didn't work. Hope someone can guide me solve this problem. Thanks.

```html
select count(created) as sum_row,created, count(created) AS total_row
from payment_details
group by created
```

Result table

```html
sum_row |   created    | total_row
   1      2020-06-17       1
   1      2020-06-19       1
   1      2020-06-25       1
   1      2020-07-17       1
   1      2020-07-22       1
```

I want the expected table result like below, want to count total row in the selected table.

```html
sum_row 
   5
```

Comment: Use this select count(*) as sum_row from payment_details

Comment: Your expected result and query you are trying is totally different as in expected output you only want total rows count, while in query you are returning 2-3 columns. Can you provide complete expected result format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want the total no of rows in the `sum-row` column ? Use the `OVER()` clause.

```
select count(created) OVER() as sum_row,
       created, 
       count(created) AS total_row 
from   payment_details  
GROUP BY created
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it's what you want.
I write this code in ms sql server 2014.

```
;with cte as(
select created, COUNT(created) over(partition by null) as total_row
from payment_details
)
select COUNT(created) as sum_row, created, total_row
from cte
group by created, total_row
```